# The Idea of a Limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider the following Definitions
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(a+i\Delta x)\Delta x\ ,\ \Delta x_=\frac{b-a}{N}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\forall\epsilon\in\mathbf{R^+}\exists M\in\mathbf{Z^+}\forall n\in\mathbf{Z^+}(n>M\implies|\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(a+i\Delta x)\Delta x-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|<\epsilon)$$
and the all too familiar 
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\forall\epsilon>0\exists \delta>0\forall x(0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon)$$
Now I am certain i understand what each of these defintions mean but what i cannot comprehend is that how do each of them in there respective contexts encapsulate the *intutitve* idea that we all have.

Which in the case of the first definitionn is the idea of the partial sum *approaching* or *converging* to the value indicated by the intgeral.

In the case of the second, the idea of the function *approaching* a certain target as $x$ gets suffciently close to $a.$

How do each of these definitions capture the aforementioned intuition inherent to our idea of a limit ?

*Apologies for the long windedness of the question

Comment: Not sure if this really addresses your question, but maybe the topological perspective can be unifying here: for every open neighborhood $U$ of $L$, there's an open neighborhood $V$ of $a$ such that $f(V) \subset U$.

Comment: Then the first case amounts to thinking of large $N$'s as belonging to "small" neighborhoods of $\infty$.

Comment: In (1) we don't have "partial sums", but completed Riemann sums $S_N$, and we look at $\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N$. – Note that the final version of the integral definition makes use of a much more intricate limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every limit is a statement that one inequality implies another inequality.

The first one says that when $n$ is very large $(n>M)$, then the corresponding Riemann sum is very close to the integral $\left(\left|\sum - \int\right|<\epsilon\right)$. The second one says that, when $x$ is very close to $a$ $(|x-a|<\delta)$, then $f(x)$ is very close to the limiting value $\left(|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\right)$.